# Loop infinito con Scanner

Tags: java, scanner

qué tal?

Tengo el siguiente código que debe sumar 10 números ingresados por el usuario. Chequea si el número ingresado es válido (sólo números), caso contrario da mensaje de error y vuelve a solicitar un número válido.

El problema que estoy teniendo es que si alguno de esos 10 números es una letra por ejemplo, da el mensaje de error pero entra en un loop infinito.

Logré frenar el loop agregando una línea de **scanner.nextLine()** casi al final, pero no entiendo por qué eso funciona ya que no entra en loop infinito si los valores ingresados son números (y en ambos casos entre valor y valor avanzo con un *enter*).

```
    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int counter = 1;
        int sum = 0;


        while (counter < 10) {
            System.out.println("Enter number #" + counter);

            boolean hasNextInt = scanner.hasNextInt(); // chequea si el proximo input es un int

            if (hasNextInt) {
                int number = scanner.nextInt();
                counter++;
                sum += number;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid number");

            }
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("Sum of numbers = " + sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en la forma en que usas los métodos [`hasNextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()) y [`nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt(int)).

Si leemos la documentación:

**hasNextInt**:

> Devuelve `true` si el valor del siguiente `token` de entrada de este `scanner` puede ser interpretado como un valor tipo `int` ...

**nextInt**:

> Escanea el siguiente `token` de la entrada como `int`. Este método arrojará una `InputMismatchException` si el siguiente `token` no puede ser convertido a un valor `int` válido ... Si la conversión es satisfactoria, el `scanner` avanzará hasta después de la entrada  que coincide.

Tu bloque de decisión entonces sólo ingresará en la primera condición (`if (hasNextInt)`) si se cumple lo que vimos en la documentación.

Cuando el usuario ingresa un valor entero válido, se ingresa en la primera condición y no tienes problemas, pero cuando no se introduce un valor inválido ocurre el problema.

**PROBLEMA**

Cuando lees la entrada usando el método [`nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt(int)), se lee sólo el `token` que coincida con un valor `int`, pero sólo lee dicho `token`, no se sigue leyendo más.

Esto quiere decir que si se introduce lo siguiente:

```
6 5 4
```

se leerá sólo el valor 6 y el resto queda allí.

Claramente no es un valor numérico válido para una entrada simple, pero para el método `nextInt()` lo es, ya que la entrada se compone de sólo números enteros separados por espacios.

¿Y qué sucede con el resto de números, y con los espacios entre ellos?

Pues que serán válidos también, y los espacios entre ellos son considerados como delimitadores entre números. Veamos lo que dice la documentación de la clase [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> Un `scanner` rompe o separa su entrada en `tokens` usando un patrón de delimitación, el cual por defecto coincide con un espacio en blanco.

El resto de números seguirán estando allí como `tokens` válidos y serán devueltos uno a uno por cada llamada a `nextInt()`.

De hecho en tu programa se puede hacer lo siguiente y el resultado será:

```sh
Enter number #1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Enter number #2
Enter number #3
Enter number #4
Enter number #5
Enter number #6
Enter number #7
Enter number #8
Enter number #9
Enter number #10
Sum of numbers = 55
```

Esto puede considerarse como un `bug` en tu programa, y aunque no da errores ciertamente es un problema.

**SOLUCION**

Ya tu has hallado una forma de detener el bucle infinito usando [`nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()), cuya documentación claramente establece lo siguiente:

> Avanza el `scanner` más allá de la línea actual y devuelve la entrada que se omitió. Este método devuelve el resto de la línea actual excluyendo cualquier salto de línea final. La posición se establece al inicio de la siguiente línea.

Entonces una solución es descartar el resto de la linea una vez obtenido el valor que nos importa. Y esto podemos hacerlo en cada iteración (justo lo que haces al agregar ese método al final de tu bucle).

Por lo tanto si se introduce más de un valor separado por espacios, se leerá el primero y el resto será descartado cuando se llama `nextLine()`.

Otra forma de resolver el problema es usar `nextLine()` directamente e intentar la conversión de la entrada a un tipo `int`. Esto nos da un control total sobre toda la linea ingresada por el usuario.

Por ejemplo:

```java
System.out.println("Enter number #" + count);
try {
  int number = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
  sum += number;
  count++;
}
catch(Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Invalid number");
}
```

En este ejemplo estoy usando un bloque `try catch`, ya que usaré el método [`parseInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) de la clase [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html).

Si la entrada es convertida satisfactoriamente a `int`, se realiza la suma y se itera nuevamente. En cambio si la entrada no puede ser convertida a `int`, el método `parseInt()` arrojará un error, el cual capturo en la sección `catch` y muestro el mensaje pertinente.

Ahora, si un usuario ingresa algo como:

```
3 4 5
```

el programa le mostrará el mensaje de número inválido y volverá a pedirle la entrada:

```sh
Enter number #1
3 4 5
Invalid number
Enter number #1
```

Espero que esto aclare un poco el problema que se te ha presentado y te ayude a entender el porqué de la solución que tú mismo hallaste.

Comment: Espectacular la explicación, gracias por tomarte el tiempo! Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se ingresa un número se hace la llamada al método `scanner.nextInt();` Este método saca el valor ingresado en el  buffer de entrada y el buffer queda vacío.

Por qué se crea un loop infinito cuando no colocas el `scanner.nextLine();`? Es por la razón anterior, si el valor ingresado no es número entonces se ignora lo que se ha ingresado en el buffer de entrada pero el buffer nunca se limpia por eso en la siguiente ejecución del ciclo while se vuelve a llamar al método `scanner.hasNextInt()`, y como el buffer contiene un valor pero el valor no es entero retorna false y así se inicia el loop.

Por qué no hay un loop infinito al colocar el método `scanner.nextLine();`? Porque cuando el valor ingresado no es número el método `nextLine()` lee el buffer y lo deja vacío.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es que pregunte hasta que ingrese el numero correcto esto te puede servir

```
public static int IngresoNumero() {     
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    String cadena = entrada.nextLine();
    while(true) {
        try {
            int X = Integer.parseInt(cadena);
            return X;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.print("Ingrese numero :");
            cadena = entrada.nextLine();
        }
    }       
}
```

El codigo pregunta constantemente por un numero hasta que reciba uno valido.
Lo puedes llamar desde el while y no deberia haber problemas.